# Polish your mug idiom

Tags: idioms, offensive-language, figures-of-speech

Recently I've heard couple of interesting idioms one of which was "Make yourself scarce or I'll polish your mug".
So, I was wondering is it really used like that?
I've heard of "Make yourself scarce" before, but "I'll polish your mug" is the first time I heard it.
Does it sounds natural? Can I actually use it? Or will it be just funny if I say it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't consider that to be offensive- more like jocular.  *Mug* is a slang term for *face*.  To "*polish your mug*" means he's going to beat you up.

> [***mug***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mug&searchmode=none) : "a person's face," 1708
>
> [***polish***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=polish&allowed_in_frame=0) : from Latin polire "to polish, make smooth; decorate, embellish

Presumably the "embellishment" to your face will consist of a bunch of cuts and bruises.

Comment: Well, I understand the meaning, but I was wondering if I can actually use this phrase and not look weird. For example if I want to say it to my buddy as a joke when he does something I don't appreciate.

Comment: You can use the phrase if you feel comfortable using it, if you feel that it is "in character" for you,  and if you think your audience (your friend) will understand it.  The effectiveness of a joke is all in the delivery. So you must be comfortable in order for a good, smooth and timely delivery- otherwise it will fall flat.

Comment: I imaging *polishing* is intended to evoke the image of forcefully rubbing something, not so much 'decorating' or 'embellishing'.

Comment: @p.s.w.g- I had that thought as well, but after thinking some about it I don't believe that any more.  Perhaps if it was a boxing metaphor involving lots of glancing blows the glove leather might "polish" the face, or if you were threatening to *polish* their face on the sidewalk maybe, but I think *decorate* or *embellish* fits much better in this particular case.

Comment: Presumably you are trying to be humorous anyway, unless you intend walking round threatening to beat people up? So if it sounds out of character for you, you'll just get a bigger laugh.